# How to control the position of the nodes

Tags: graphviz, dot

Just two short questions. Let's consider the following code from Graphviz:

```
digraph EXAMPLE {

splines="line";
node[shape=circle, fontname="Verdana"];
ranksep=1;

SC -> {00, 01} -> {02, 03} -> {FC}
SU -> {13, 12, 10} -> {11} -> {FU}
SD -> {22} -> {23, 21, 20} -> {FD}
ST -> {31, 32} -> {33, 30} -> {FT}

S -> {SC ; SU ; SD ; ST}
{FC ; FU ; FD ; FT} -> F

}
```

That is rendering the following:

[image: Graphviz]

I have two questions:

1. How can I make that node "11" appears in the same vertical level as node "12"?
2. How can attain that the horizontal distance between nodes "SC", "SU", "SD", and "ST" would be the same?

Thank you in advance!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Giving multiple nodes the same **group** (https://graphviz.org/docs/attrs/group/) value *usually* results on vertical (horizontal) edges
- Adding equal **weight** (https://graphviz.org/docs/attrs/weight/) values to the 4 nodes resulted in equidistant node layout.  **nodesep** (https://graphviz.org/docs/attrs/nodesep/) could also be used, but it would affect all the node separations.

```
digraph EXAMPLE {

splines="line";
node[shape=circle, fontname="Verdana"];
ranksep=1;

{node [group=gA] 11 12 }
SC -> {00, 01} -> {02, 03} -> {FC}
SU -> {13, 12, 10} -> {11} -> {FU}
SD -> {22} -> {23, 21, 20} -> {FD}
ST -> {31, 32} -> {33, 30} -> {FT}

{
edge[weight=10]
S -> {SC ; SU ; SD ; ST}
}
{FC ; FU ; FD ; FT} -> F

}
```

Giving:
[image]